# How to remove rows containing one pattern but not another pattern in r

Tags: r

I am wanting to filter a dataframe similar to this one:

```
testdf <- data.frame(notes = c("=-@progress note on lung cancer with family history of prostate cancer", "breast cancer", "lung cancer and breast cancer", "ICD10: rectal cancer", "PN dx left side gastric cancer", "gastric cancer and breast cancer", "No additional data on esophagus condition: score satisfactory", "~icd78: C13.78- Malignant growth of base of pancreas"), sample = c("tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor", "tumor"))

> testdf
                                                                   notes sample
1 =-@progress note on lung cancer with family history of prostate cancer  tumor
2                                                          breast cancer  tumor
3                                          lung cancer and breast cancer  tumor
4                                                   ICD10: rectal cancer  tumor
5                                         PN dx left side gastric cancer  tumor
6                                       gastric cancer and breast cancer  tumor
7          No additional data on esophagus condition: score satisfactory  tumor
8                   ~icd78: C13.78- Malignant growth of base of pancreas  tumor
```

Where I want to remove rows 1,4, 5, and 8 because the `notes` column contains "lung", "rectal", "gastric", and "pancreas", BUT keep rows 2, 3, and 6 because it contains the word "breast", and keep row 7 as well; like this:

```
                                                            notes         sample
2                                                          breast cancer  tumor
3                                          lung cancer and breast cancer  tumor
6                                       gastric cancer and breast cancer  tumor
7          No additional data on esophagus condition: score satisfactory  tumor
```

I can remove rows based on it having the words "lung", "rectal", "gastric", or "pancreas", but this removes rows 3 and 6, which I don't want.

```
testdf_filtered <- testdf[!grepl(pattern = 'lung|rectal|gastric|pancreas', x = testdf$notes),]

                                                          notes sample
2                                                 breast cancer  tumor
7 No additional data on esophagus condition: score satisfactory  tumor
```

I am not sure how to have the occurrence of the word "breast", override this (hence keeping rows 3 and 6), and basically ignore row 7 and leave it as it is.

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT: changed the example to be more reflective of the actual data**

Comment: `subset(df, grepl('breast', notes))`

Comment: Hi @onyambu! I realize I needed to clarify my question - not all of the rows I want contain the word "breast" I should say. I just want to remove the rows with"lung", "gastric", or "rectal", but keep any rows with the word "breast" and ignore everything else

Comment: do those words contain the word `cancer` after them?

Comment: not necessarily unfortunately

Comment: Then this is more complex than you thing. eg do you have the word `and` when combining two or more cancers?, what other words can a single line contain etc.

Comment: Hi @onyambu, I'm beginning to see what you mean a little heh. There's not a real clear pattern, it's just condition notes (as in human written notes with no definitive structure to it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simply retain the rows that have

1. "breast" OR
2. don't have lung|rectal|gastric

```
testdf %>%
  filter(!grepl("lung|rectal|gastric", notes) | grepl("breast", notes))
```

Comment: This wont work because it is using the word `breast`. Note that OP states that they can have different cancers. eg thsi will ignore `lung cancer and throat cancer` for example

Comment: @onyambu should such a row be retained?

Comment: yes, it contains another type apart from `lung` just like `lung and breast` is retained. But `lung and gastric` should be removed.

Comment: `breast` is an example of what the row can contain. But they can contain other words also

Comment: perhaps the OP could explicitly show such a row in the example?

Comment: Hi langtang and @onyambu, I made the example more like the original data - I unfortunately am not allowed to actually share it, but there's no real pattern unfortunately.

Comment: My simple approach still works on your example data. Can you please provide an example of a row that my solution drops, but that you wish it would retain?  Or, an example of a row that my solution retains, but that you wish would be dropped?

Comment: Hi langtang and @onyambu! I think your solution does hold, langtang! It's really I want to remove any mention of "pancreas" (I added another example row), "lung", "gastric", etc (whether it's "lung cancer" or "has something in the lung") but not if it has any mention of "breast" (whether it be "breast cancer", "has history of breast lesion", etc.). If that makes sense? I'll accept your answer as the answer though now. Thank you both so much for your help!